# How to merge two ubuntu one accounts?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I created a Ubuntu one account long time ago, recently, forgetting that, I created another ubuntu one account using a different email address. As a result,I have two set of synced folders and both are different. 
Is there a way I can merge both?

Comment: here is what i did. removed the device from my installation in windows, and the wizard started all over, i used the earlier account during the setup. this way, i don't have two separate accounts; however, there is one dummy/dead account which i will never use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually while looking at launchpad some where I've seen that we can merge or attach two launchedpad accounts as a single one .

to login ubuntu one you also need to use launched login . so what I'm thinking is if you merge there in lunchpad then with single login you can access both ubuntuone accounts .

give a try .

Comment: This did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Merging Two Ubuntu One accounts , please consider contacting the [Support team here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) and explain in detail what exactly you want.

Alternately ,

As far as merging the Contents is Concerned  , just **copy the Contents of U1 account File** to U2 account Ubuntu one File and **sync it to Ub8untu One cloud from your Ubuntu One U2 account Control panel.**

**Legend** : Your earlier Ubuntu one Account = **U1** , and current new Ubuntu One account **U2**.